# Finding Non Duplicate entries in Excel

Tags: excel

I Have a column which contains multiple unique and duplicate values and I'm looking to extract only the non repeating values. How do i go about it?

Example:

A2: 28; 33; 34; 37; 44

A3: 28; 34; 37

I'm trying to get:

A4: 33; 44

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARjnd.png)

I've tried finding an answer but couldn't find a solution for this exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Result]

=LET(a,TEXTJOIN(";",,B2:B4),UNIQUE(--TEXTSPLIT(a,";"),TRUE,TRUE))

Comment: I tried using this but I'm just getting an error.

Comment: Neat use of Unique

Comment: can show me the error what you are getting.. @quite.

Comment: @quite Note that your delimiter contains a space `"; "` while your data is in the range `A2:A3`.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t see a way of doing this using only formulas. The best approach would be to save those values as a .csv file, and importing that csv file into Excel. Then, using Power Query, you would do the necessary transformations in order to get the desired result.

Here is a step by step solution:

1. Get your data into a .csv file
2. Import the csv file by going into Data > From Text/CSV,= and selecting the file. Then, select the delimiter "Semicolon" and click "Transform Data" to open Power Query:

[image: Power Query import]

3. With Power Query open, select all columns by pressing Ctrl + A, and then go to the "Transform" tab and click "Unpivot Columns". You should have something like this:

[image: Power Query unpivoted columns]

4. Delete the "Attribute" column
5. Remove duplicates from "Value" column
6. Click "Close & Load" in the Home tab

You then will have the desired result:

[image: Final result]

Comment: Thanks for trying to find a solution but you didn't achieve the result I'm trying to get.  The goal is to extract only the numbers which have not been repeated in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer which ignores any spaces between the values and formats the result by putting only one space between the values. Call the function with two parameters, the values of the two cells to be merged:

```
    Public Function Uniques(stra As String, strb As String) As String
'Uniques("11; 12; 13;  14;   15", " 11;11;  14;  15; 88; 16 ") ==> "12; 13; 88; 16"
   Dim ar() As String, delim As String, ss As String, s As String, alen As Integer
   Dim z As Integer, p As Integer, c As Integer
   delim = ";"
   s = Replace(stra & delim & strb, " ", "")
   ar = Split(s, delim)
   s = delim & s & delim
   alen = UBound(ar)
   For c = 0 To alen
      If ar(c) <> "" Then
         ss = delim & ar(c) & delim
         p = InStr(1, s, ss)
         If (p > 0) Then
            p = InStr(p + 1, s, ss)
            If p > 0 Then
               s = Replace(s, delim & ar(c), "")
               For z = c + 1 To alen
                  If ar(z) = ar(c) Then ar(z) = ""
               Next
            End If
         End If
      End If
   Next
   If (s = delim) Then
      Uniques = ""
   Else
      s = Mid(s, 2, Len(s) - 2)
      s = Replace(s, delim, delim & " ")
      Uniques = s
   End If
End Function
```

if the two cells have the same value returns empty string ("")

Comment: Should've mentioned it in the post but I'm attempting to do it only by using excel. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reduce, Textsplit and Hstack to split each row and add it to a single-row array, then use Reduce again to check the number of times each element of the array occurs, and concatenate it to the output if it only occurs once.

```
=LET(
    data, DROP(
        TOCOL(A:A, 1),
        1
    ),
    row, DROP(
        REDUCE(
            "",
            data,
            LAMBDA(a, c,
                HSTACK(
                    a,
                    TEXTSPLIT(
                        c,
                        "; "
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        ,
        1
    ),
    MID(
        REDUCE(
            "",
            row,
            LAMBDA(a, c,
                IF(
                    SUM(
                        N(
                            c =
                                row
                        )
                    ) = 1,
                    a & "; " &
                        c,
                    a
                )
            )
        ),
        3,
        99
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: I've given this a try and set it up the same way you did but I'm getting an error. Don't know if it's due to the software version or something else...

Comment: What error message are you getting?