# EXCEL - Is there a formula for TEXTSPLIT from 3 different rows into a sequencing of rows without data /text duplication?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, formula

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a, b, c |  | a |
| a, c, e |  | b |
| b, a, d |  | c |
|  |  | d |
|  |  | e |

I can do the textsplit but I want the three rows from Column A to be like in the Column C, combine the three rows into one sequencing rows in split text and without duplication.

Comment: Can you show the o/p what you are expecting???

Comment: [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75420718/finding-non-duplicate-entries-in-excel/75425225?noredirect=1#comment133091882_75425225)
 have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

### SORT a UNIQUE TEXTSPLIT To Column

**Simple**

- Be aware of the `TEXTJOIN` limitation.

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",,A2:A4),,", ")))
```

**Practice REDUCE**

```
=SORT(DROP(REDUCE("",A2:A4,LAMBDA(cResult,cCell,
    UNIQUE(VSTACK(cResult,TEXTSPLIT(cCell,,", "))))),1))
```

**A `LAMBDA` Function**

- In the Ribbon, select *Formulas->Defined Names->Define Name*.
- Under `Name`, input the function name e.g. `SplitDelColumn`, under `Comment`, add a short description, and under `Refers to` enter the following formula:

```
=LAMBDA(Data,Delimiter,SORT(DROP(REDUCE("",Data,LAMBDA(cRow,cCell,
    UNIQUE(VSTACK(cRow,TEXTSPLIT(cCell,,Delimiter))))),1)))
```

- Now you can use it like any other Excel function:

```
=SplitDelColumn(A2:A4,", ")
```

- Note that you can do the same with the simple formula.

Comment: I had the same idea, but I see you already posted it. I guess for `TEXTJOIN` you don't need to specify the second input argument, since it is the default value (`1` or `TRUE`), but it saves one character only, :-). Nice solution.

Comment: @DavidLeal Thanks. Corrected. More importantly, I also removed the redundant use of `TOCOL` whose functionality can be achieved by using the 3rd argument (*row_delimiter*) of `TEXTSPLIT` (instead of the 2nd (*col_delimiter*)).